# UI Freeze after launching the thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

I have a problem and i've been looking so hard and i didnt get lucky to find the right answer here my problem is when i call the function **dosomeWork()** using **BackgroundWorker()** in the thread, the UI freeze compeletely.
i already added the controls of the From1 to delegate to avoid update thread errors.

```
        public void dosomeWork()
        {
.
.
.
           for (int i = 0; i <= listline.Count; i += range)
                {
                    status.Text = "test if i can change label name without freezing";
                    isChecked(listline.GetRange(i, range));

                }

            }

        }
```

delegate function

```
        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Delegate del = new DELEGATE(dosomeWork);
            this.Invoke(del);
            Delegate del2 = new TheMethod(isChecked);
            this.Invoke(del2);

        }
```

BackgroundWorker function

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

normally its should works properly. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a separate thread to change something in the GUI thread (*even though it was initiated on the GUI thread; it is still seperate*) and cross thread manipulation of GUI thread items is not allowed for reasons you are experiencing. That is why it is freezing.

---

You need to invoke the operation back to the GUI thread for all GUI related variables and controls. Here is a method I use in my VM:

```
public static void SafeOperationToGuiThread(Action operation)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(operation);
}
```

You would use as such:

```
        public void dosomeWork()
        {

           for (int i = 0; i <= listline.Count; i += range)
                {

                MyVM.SafeOperationToGuiThread( () => { 
                    status.Text = "test if i can change label name without freezing";
                    isChecked(listline.GetRange(i, range));
                      }

                }

            }

        }
```

---

I had run into this too when I changed a property, instead of a control, and discovered that controls and properties are not immune to cross thread manipulation. Here is my article:

[C# WPF: Linq Fails in BackgroundWorker DoWork](http://omegacoder.com/?p=636)

---

**Alternate Option**

Note one can also update a gui via background work if one provides a *run worker completed* delegate and then one does not have to invoke back to the GUI. I provide an example on my blog:

[C# WPF: Threading, Control Updating, Status Bar and Cancel Operations Example All In One](http://omegacoder.com/?p=642)